# Can Property File be configured for a particular module/Layer in JAVA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Java Spring MVC application having 3 layers which is a very standard architecture

> Controller
>
> Service
>
> DAO

Each of these layers is maintained using separate Spring context files. 
Each layer maintains its own property file.

```
Controller => controller-context.xml => controller.properties
Service => service-context.xml => service.properties
Dao => dao-context.xml => dao.properties
```

I have configured DAO layer as below.

**dao.properties**

```
db.url=admin@localhost:1028/test
db.user=admin
db.password=admin
```

**dao-context.xml**

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurerDB" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
       <list>
           <value>classpath:dao.properties</value>
       </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

When i load all these context files and properties files, every property is available or can be injected in any layer be it **Controller** or **Service** or **DAO** meaning the properties are global.

Is there any configuration which i need to have so that **dao.properties** should be only used by **DAO** layer?

Comment: Do you want the dao.properties to be used by dao layer only or you want the dao-context.xml to be used by dao layer ?

Comment: What i am trying to acheive is dao.properties should only be used by DAO layer classes.

Comment: Not without making your whole application loading more complex. That would also mean you need 3 seperate application contexts for each layer, where there controller has service as a parent and the service the dao. So the short answer is no you cannot, not without adding additional layers of complexity to your appliation or discarding the spring `@Value` support.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the annotation in your DAO classed @PropertySource("file:/{selected location}/dao.properties") where you have used @Value annotation. To fetch the values in the code you can have a separate loader of each of the properties which implement a common interface (MyApplicationPropertyLoader here). Now you can choose which implementation will be used of this interface to load properties in dao-config.properties.

```
        public class DaoPropertiesLoader extends MyApplicationPropertyLoader{

          private static Properties appProperties = null;

          public static Properties getProperties() {
                if (appProperties == null || appProperties.isEmpty()) {.
                    appProperties =propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
                } 
                return appProperties;
            }

            public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
                PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
                properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("{selected location}/dao.properties"));
                properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
                return properties;
            }

@Override
    public String getExternalProperty(String property) {
            String propertyVal = getProperties().getProperty(property); 
            return propertyVal;
        }

        }
```

But the catch here is you will now have to use MyApplicationPropertyLoader.getExternalProperty() everywhere to fetch the value in DaoLayer.